# Can I enable suppressions with checkstyle, the maven-checkstyle-plugin and google_checks.xml?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I would like to do the following:

1. Use the standard google_checks.xml configuration, because I don't want to duplicate it.
2. Be able to suppress warnings, in particular for generated code, but potentially also for false positives.
3. Use the maven-checkstyle-plugin.

As far as I can understand, in order to be able to use suppressions, you need to add a filter to the .xml configuration, and the google_checks.xml configuration is something I'd rather not own myself. Is it possible to solve this? It would be nice if project-specific things like suppressions would be separated from more generic things like the code style rules.

Comment: You can configure an `<excludes>`, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362652/excluding-classes-in-maven-checkstyle-plugin-reports

Comment: Thanks, that helps some but doesn't quite seem to give full access to suppressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around what feels like a deficiency in checkstyle by creating a separate checkstyle configuration based on the google_checks.xml, and making that available as a separate Maven artifact. The result is here: https://github.com/spotify/spotify-checkstyle-config.

It means we will duplicate the google_checks.xml configuration, but only once.