# Disable generated source directories from checkstyle maven plugin

Tags: maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

In a multi modules project, there is one generating some source code in the directory `target/generated-sources/xjc3/com/...` and I'm trying to make the maven checkstyle plugin to skip this generated source directory. Despite having tried many syntax for the `<excludes>` tag, it keeps scanning this source directory. **Does any know how to remove this generated source directory from the audit?**

### Maven plugin configuration

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.cloudstack</groupId>
          <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
          <version>8.7</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>cloudstack-checkstyle</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <configLocation>cloud-style.xml</configLocation>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
        <includes>**\/*.java</includes>
        <excludes>**\/deps\/,**\/test\/,**\/target\/,**\/bin\/,**\/*.xml,**\/*.ini,**\/*.sh,**\/*.bat,**\/apidoc\/,**\/generated-sources\/,**\/generated-sources\/*,**\/generated-sources\/**,**\/generated-sources\/**\/*.*,**/generated-sources/**/*.*,**/generated-sources/**/*,**/generated-sources/**,**/generated-sources/*,**/generated-sources/*.*</excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

### Maven run debug output

This is the plugin debug output, which shows that it keeps including the generated source directory:

```
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (cloudstack-checkstyle) @ cloud-plugin-network-vcs ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@74a14482]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) cacheFile = /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/checkstyle-cachefile
[DEBUG]   (f) configLocation = cloud-style.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) consoleOutput = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) excludes = **\/deps\/,**\/test\/,**\/target\/,**\/bin\/,**\/*.xml,**\/*.ini,**\/*.sh,**\/*.bat,**\/apidoc\/,**\/generated-sources\/,**\/generated-sources\/*,**\/generated-sources\/**,**\/generated-sources\/**\/*.*,**/generated-sources/**/*.*,**/generated-sources/**/*,**/generated-sources/**,**/generated-sources/*,**/generated-sources/*.*
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnViolation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) failsOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) headerLocation = LICENSE.txt
[DEBUG]   (f) includeResources = true
[DEBUG]   (f) includeTestResources = true
[DEBUG]   (f) includeTestSourceDirectory = true
[DEBUG]   (f) includes = **\/*.java
[DEBUG]   (f) logViolationsToConsole = true
[DEBUG]   (f) maxAllowedViolations = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) omitIgnoredModules = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputFile = /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/checkstyle-result.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) outputFileFormat = xml
[DEBUG]   (f) plugin = Component Descriptor: role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo', role hint: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleReport', role hint: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:checkstyle'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleAggregateReport', role hint: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:checkstyle-aggregate'
role: 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo', implementation: 'org.apache.maven.plugins.checkstyle.HelpMojo', role hint: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:help'
---
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.apache.cloudstack:cloud-plugin-network-vcs:4.12.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) resourceIncludes = **/*.properties
[DEBUG]   (f) resources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/src/main/resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}, Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc1, PatternSet [includes: {**/jaxb.properties, **/bgm.ser}, excludes: {}]}}, Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc2, PatternSet [includes: {**/jaxb.properties, **/bgm.ser}, excludes: {}]}}, Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc3, PatternSet [includes: {**/jaxb.properties, **/bgm.ser}, excludes: {}]}}, Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/maven-shared-archive-resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}]
[DEBUG]   (f) rulesFiles = /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/checkstyle-rules.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipExec = false
[DEBUG]   (f) suppressionsFileExpression = checkstyle.suppressions.file
[DEBUG]   (f) testResources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/src/test/resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}, Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/maven-shared-archive-resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}]
[DEBUG]   (f) violationSeverity = error
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] executeCheckstyle start headerLocation : LICENSE.txt
[DEBUG] Added 27 source files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/src/main/java'.
[DEBUG] Added 5 source files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc1'.
[DEBUG] Added 5 source files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc2'.
[DEBUG] Added 7 source files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc3'.
[DEBUG] Added 0 source files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/annotations'.
[DEBUG] Added 3 test source files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/src/test/java'.
[DEBUG] Added 0 test source files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations'.
[DEBUG] Added 1 resource files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/src/main/resources'.
[DEBUG] Added 0 resource files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc1'.
[DEBUG] Added 0 resource files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc2'.
[DEBUG] Added 0 resource files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc3'.
[DEBUG] Added 0 resource files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/maven-shared-archive-resources'.
[DEBUG] The resources directory '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/src/test/resources' does not exist or is not a directory.
[DEBUG] Added 0 resource files found in '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/maven-shared-archive-resources'.
[DEBUG] Added 48 files to process.
[DEBUG] Adding the outputDirectory file:/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/classes/ to the Checkstyle class path
[DEBUG] Adding the outputDirectory file:/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/test-classes/ to the Checkstyle class path
[DEBUG] request.getConfigLocation() cloud-style.xml
[DEBUG] The resource 'cloud-style.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'cloud-style.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.JarResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: No valid URL 'cloud-style.xml'
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: No valid URL 'cloud-style.xml'
[DEBUG] The resource 'cloud-style.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'cloud-style.xml' was found as jar:file:/home/marco/.m2/repository/org/apache/cloudstack/checkstyle/4.12.0.0-SNAPSHOT/checkstyle-4.12.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/cloud-style.xml.
[DEBUG] headerLocation LICENSE.txt
[DEBUG] The resource 'LICENSE.txt' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] JarResourceLoader : trying to load "jar:file:/home/marco/.m2/repository/org/apache/cloudstack/checkstyle/4.12.0.0-SNAPSHOT/checkstyle-4.12.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
[DEBUG] JarResourceLoader : trying to load "jar:file:/home/marco/.m2/repository/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/8.7/checkstyle-8.7.jar"
[DEBUG] The resource 'LICENSE.txt' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.JarResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: No valid URL 'LICENSE.txt'
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: No valid URL 'LICENSE.txt'
[DEBUG] The resource 'LICENSE.txt' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] Unable to process header location: LICENSE.txt
[DEBUG] Checkstyle will throw exception if ${checkstyle.header.file} is used
[DEBUG] Added '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/src/main/resources' as a source directory.
[DEBUG] Added '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc1' as a source directory.
[DEBUG] Added '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc2' as a source directory.
[DEBUG] Added '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc3' as a source directory.
[DEBUG] Added '/home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/maven-shared-archive-resources' as a source directory.
[INFO] Starting audit...
[ERROR] /home/marco/code/cloudstack-public/plugins/network-elements/brocade-vcs/target/generated-sources/xjc1/com/cloud/network/schema/interfacevlan/ObjectFactory.java:2: Line has trailing spaces. [RegexpSingleline]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your modules have consistent source folder location, you may lock source folders to 'real' sources

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectories>
            <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        </sourceDirectories>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or (preferrably), to include both sources and tests

```
<sourceDirectories>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory> 
    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory> 
</sourceDirectories>
```

Comment: As discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406454/6825678 this approach should solve the issue. Alternatively you could a SuppressionFilter.

Comment: Better with:

             <sourceDirectories>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
            </sourceDirectories>

Thanks for pointing to this post, I could fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also running code generation in maven which also adds the target/generated as a source dir and makes any source dir filtering options in checkstyle useless.

The following solution works:
You have to use an explicit checkstyle-suppressions.xml config file and activate it from your configuration:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
      <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
   [...]
```

The suppressions file for excluding the target folder looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
  "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
  "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">

<suppressions>
  <suppress files="[/\\]target[/\\]" checks=".*" />
</suppressions>
```