# How to exclude a file in the source root from Maven Checkstyle plugin checks?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I found [Excluding classes in Maven Checkstyle plugin reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362652/excluding-classes-in-maven-checkstyle-plugin-reports) which explains well how to exclude classes with

```
<configuration>
  <excludes>**/package/...,**/otherpackage/...</excludes>
</configuration>
```

However, I don't seem to get how to exclude a file like `LICENSE.txt` in the source root.

I tried (for `LICENSE.txt` and `NOTICE.txt`)

```
<excludes>**/LICENSE.txt,**/NOTICE.txt</excludes>
```

and

```
<excludes>LICENSE.txt,NOTICE.txt</excludes>
```

which both still produce a warning for a missing license header.

The concrete project I'm trying to apply this on is [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://github.com/apache/commons-fileupload).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Surppressions Filter:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html

Comment: @KarlRichter did you ever get that `<excludes>` tag to work? I have the same issues right now and tried almost all the possible combination of the url. Can't seem to get it working

Comment: @Gurkha No, I'm sticking with suppressions-filter for some time.

Comment: @KarlRichter I got it to work, posted answer below for future references.

Answer (score 1):

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>org/path/to/your/domain/*.java</excludes>
                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>checkstyle</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The Above configuration works for me. Previously I had `<configuration>` tag inside `<executions>` block which was creating issues excluding the classes. It should be outside of `<executions>` tag.