# Exclude *target* directory from the maven-checkstyle-plugin scan

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am using Apache Maven Checkstyle plugin in my pom.xml.
I am trying to exclude the target directory from the check style scan but no luck so far. Here is the pom code i am trying.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>checkstyle-check</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyles.xml</configLocation>
                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <includes>**\/*.java,**\/*.groovy</includes>
                <excludes>**WHAT GOES HERE TO EXCLUDE THE TARGET DIRECTORY**</excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Doesn't it automatically exclude output directories by default?

Comment: This one is already discussed here with suggested solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362652/excluding-classes-in-maven-checkstyle-plugin-reports

Answer (score 5):

In Apache Maven Checkstyle Plugin version 3 to specify the location of the source directories we have to use [sourceDirectories](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#sourceDirectories) parameter. Then we can specify only directories of application/library and test sources to be used for Checkstyle:

```xml
<sourceDirectories>
  <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
  <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
</sourceDirectories>
```

Now only `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` will be analysed.

Here is my full working example:

```xml
<!-- Apache Maven Checkstyle Plugin (checks Java code adheres to a coding standard) -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <sourceDirectories>
      <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
      <sourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
    </sourceDirectories>
    <!-- relates to https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml -->
    <configLocation>/src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<excludes>**/generated/**/*</excludes>
```

This will remove the generated files from the plugin.